# Alternative to saying "good night" on remote meetings

Tags: professionalism, communication, meetings

I have a weekly Skype meeting with a colleague who lives on another continent.

Our meeting happens in the morning for me and in the night time for him (around 9pm). He always starts out the meeting with

> "Good morning ->my name<-"

Even though it isn't morning for him.

I want to say

> Good night -> his name <-

But maybe it's just something in my head but "Good Night" seems like a way to say "bye" and not a greeting. So what can I say instead that would reflect that I am greeting him at his night time.

I tried:

> Good Evening

but he joked that it was night time there. I don't want to make the same awkward joke every week. What could I say instead that is friendly yet professional?

My race/culture : South Asian in the USA 
Colleague's culture: Middle Eastern

Comment: @JoeStrazzere or perhaps the coworker was just taking advantage of the situation to joke around a bit before starting the meeting :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What could I say instead that is friendly yet professional?

The most neutral (yet friendly) and professional way I can think of is *"Greetings"*.

A more friendly way of putting it could be *"Greetings [name]"*, or *"Glad to see you again, [name]"*, or even *"Hey there, [name], good to read you again"*.

Have in mind if this is written or spoken, so you say "see" or "read" properly.

Comment: but wouldn't it be awkward/disrespectful if I did not say "Good <time of the day>" to him since he wished me ? I am sorry but I'm a bit socially inept

Comment: Not necessarily, any polite reply should suffice, and don't worry sometimes these word choices can be tricky

Comment: "Good to see you again ->name<-  " sounds nice, thanks :)

Comment: @user87777 glad I could help, welcome to The Workplace BTW :)

Comment: Who says "Greetings"?  :D

Comment: @solarflare I use it sometimes... funny coincidence: I sometimes drop the "good morning" on chat, and most of the times someone will say *"It's night over here"*... the use of greetings has helped me avoid to continuously fall for that :0)

Comment: @DarkCygnus in a chat you can get away with it but if its on skype videochat and you want to say "greetings" might I suggest tipping your fedora as well to complete the look :P  tl;dr no one uses that term in real life

Comment: @solarflare if you dont like that word, perhaps you want to consider one of the other options I provided, like Glad to see you, or Hi/hey there :)

Answer (score 3):

> What could I say instead that is friendly yet professional?

I would say "Hi [his name]" or "Hello [his name]".

There may be greetings more culturally-specific, but you didn't indicate the two cultures.

Answer (score 2):

Couple etiquette notes on conference lines. I've spent hundreds of hours on international calls for work.

1. It is pointless to try to speak within everyone else's time zone, especially on large calls that span multiple countries. It starts to sound ridiculous if you try-- "Good morning/afternoon/evening, where ever you are." People still do it, but it is kind of a distraction.
2. It is common in a professional environment to identify yourself instead of giving the usual greeting. For example, instead of "Good morning everyone" you could say "Hello, this is John." This has practical benefits since there could be numerous people on the call.
3. On a work call, it is OK to greet in your own timezone, i.e. if it's morning where you are, just say "Good morning." This has practical benefits as well, since it tells everyone on the call what time of day it is for you. They already know what time of day it is for them.

Comment: I dunno if "Hello, this is John" fits the context of this question between two people who communicate weekly, but it's exactly what I do on a bridge too.